# AND , OR clause not working for me in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have trying writing a basic SQL statement but it seem not working

`select * from table where  ( company <> 1234 OR name <> 'a=know') and type= 1`

when i run above i still see value in out put where name column have a=know value

Expected:

I want to get rows where company  doesn't have value = 1234 and column doesn't have value = a=know.

Comment: What what should be the output? Add example data and expected output

Comment: `where name column have a=know`if company is 1234 it will match your conditions

Comment: Please add more input / output data so that it is easier to help you in a more precise way.

Comment: ummm... The sql specifies **`( c1 OR c2 )`**. But we are wanting rows that match **`( c1 AND c2 )`**  ..... ummm... am I missing the question here? (note: i think the `AND` and `OR` operate per the specification; the issue is not that AND and OR are "*not working*" ...

Answer (score 2):

```
where company <> 1234 
  and name <> 'a=know'
  and type= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It should also be explained why your answer does not work as you expect.

```
select * from table where  ( company <> 1234 OR name <> 'a=know') and type= 1
```

What this will do is include all rows where `company <> 1234 OR name <> 'a=know' AND type=1`.

So all rows that do not have company equal to 1234 OR name equal to a=know will be included. You are only excluding those where both company are not 1234 AND name is not a=know.

For working implementation you should to something along the lines of:

```
WHERE company <> 1234 AND name <> 'a=know' AND type= 1
```